# Finding the Length of a Word in a String and Finding How Many Words Have That Length. Without Using Import And NLTK(Python)

Tags: python, string, list, function, dictionary

I need some help finding the length of a word and how many word have that length with tabular. For example, if the sentence is "I will buy a new bike.",

The output would be

| Length of Word | How Many Words In The Text In This Length |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 1 |

Comment: how is the second-row second column 2. when there are only 2 words with the length of 3. shouldn't it be 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below first gets rid of all punctuation marks, then split the sentence into a list of words, then creates a dictionary of lengths and counts, and finally prints the output in tabular format without importing anything.

```
sentence = "I will' buy; a new bike."

#remove punctuation marks
punctuations = ['.', ',', ';', ':', '?', '!', '-', '"', "'"]
for p in punctuations:
    sentence = sentence.replace(p, "")

#split into list of words
word_list = sentence.split()

#create a dictionary of lengths and counts
dic = {}
for word in word_list:
    if len(word) not in dic:
        dic[len(word)] = 1
    else:
        dic[len(word)] += 1

#write the dictionary as a table without importing anything (e.g.Pandas)
print('Length of word   |  Count of words of that length')
for length, count in dic.items():
    print('------------------------------------------')
    print(f'       {length}         |         {count}')


#Output:

#Length of word   |  Count of words of that length
#------------------------------------------
#       1         |         2
#------------------------------------------
#       4         |         2
#------------------------------------------
#       3         |         2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer doing it without any imports at all:

```
def wordlenghtsgrouper(phrase):
    l = [len(w) for w in phrase.replace('.','').replace(',','').split()]
    return {i:l.count(i) for i in l}
```

It returns a dictionary containing the "lengths" and a count of each ocurrence.

If you don't mind importing, you can use the Counter which is specifically does what you ask for:

```
from collections import Counter
...
def wordlenghtsgrouper(phrase):
    return Counter([len(w) for w in phrase.replace('.','').replace(',','').split()])
```

Comment: Was just writing something similar. This'll do.